# INSTALLING NUMPY ON WINDOWS 7 64 bit

Tags: python

Im trying to install numpy but cant seem to .
I have python 2.7
I downloaded numpy from the sourceforge site.
I get the following error:
No module named msvccompiler in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils 
error: unable to find vcvarsall.bat

Please help. THanks for any suggestions

Comment: Are you trying to compile it yourself?  What file did you download?

Comment: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy download the prebuilt binary here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this SO question:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat)

For Windows installations:

While running setup.py for package installations Python 2.7 searches for an installed Visual Studio 2008. You can trick Python to use a newer Visual Studio by setting the correct path in VS90COMNTOOLS environment variable before calling setup.py.

If you have Visual Studio 2010 installed, execute

SET VS90COMNTOOLS=%VS100COMNTOOLS%

or with Visual Studio 2012 installed

SET VS90COMNTOOLS=%VS110COMNTOOLS%